# CentOS 7 mysqli works on php apache but not on php-cli

Tags: mysql, centos7, php7, php-cli

I have php7.2 installed(from remi repository) in CentOS 7.5. I want to access mysqli from command line php. When trying, it shows the error:

> Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

The php running with apache works fine with mysqli. All extensions installed through yum reflects perfectly here. But for the php command line(which is parsing a different php.ini file), the extensions are not loaded.

Do I need to separately add the extensions for commandline php? If so how? Or any other alternative? Please let e know if you need any further information.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You already answered your question. The cli uses a different .ini file. Have you checked it for the loaded extensions?

Comment: Yes. The extensions are not there. How to add them in the cli ini file separately?

Comment: Your preferred text editor should suffice.

Comment: The required *.so files are not present in the extension directory designated by the cli-ini file. The web version ext files are in the format '30-mysqli.ini' which are not getting parsed by cli-ini.

Comment: Pointing the extension directory of cli-ini to the extension directory of web-ini not working. Apache restart shows error.

Comment: The remi PHP builds use the same php.ini for all PHP SAPIs. Did you mix in a version of PHP from somewhere else?

Comment: Im not sure. The php versions of both cli and httpd are same. 7.2.9.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) (thanks) in the comment, there were two php installations in the server. I have arrived at two different solutions based on specific need:

1. **For php-cli:**

> In the .bash_profile, the following line is added
>
> ```
> alias php="/usr/bin/php"
> ```

2. **For running PHP from java servlet (as command):**

> Use
>
> ```
> String[] commands = {"bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/php myphpfile.php arg01 arg02"};
> File dir = new File("<my-php-file-directory>");
> try{
> Process process;
> process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands, null, dir);
> process.waitFor();
> ....
> ....
> }
> ```

Thats all

`php -modules` in the terminal gives the desired output with mysqli.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually discuss how you solved the problem of having two incompatible PHP installations?

Comment: You're right. First of all I yum removed, cleaned the 'php' and reinstalled it from remi.